# Iphone bluetooth keyboard custom layout

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios

In Finland we have two more letters than English has. All bluetooth keyboards are however with US layout. Can I somehow change layout so buttons in corresponding places would act as these characters.

If yes, are there some restrictions for keys that I can replace? I would need two buttons to right from L-letter. Some keyboards have eg. keys "-" and "=" there but in some variants there are up arrow.

Iphone 4S with IOS 7.

Comment: @Tom: I can't find bluetooth keyboard that contains åäö at all. If these were some other place, it would be fine too. But if I could add programly ä and ö to eg. [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-MZ4uCULpg) keyboard it would be what I'm needing most.

Comment: I didn't mention it because it won't effect my question. It effects its _backgrounds._ And that long hold. Too complicated and slow.

Comment: Nope. I won't carry separate 24 cents keyboard in my pocket for my phone. You are not answering my question. I asked way to use non-Finnish keyboard with Finnish layout. So what I'm asking is if I can get ö-character from "-"-button or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth keyboards ARE available with the keys that you need.  For example Apple makes this one:

http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC184S/B/apple-wireless-keyboard

but I am sure there are others.

You have to also set the layout in iOS.  Tap on Finnish in the list of active keyboards and go to the Hardware part of the menu that appears and choose "finnish".

If for some reason you are only able to use a hardware keyboard with the US layout printed on the keys, then (after setting the Hardware layout in iOS to Finnnish) you should get ö from the ; button and ä from the ' button.

It's not possible for users to add new keyboard layouts to iOS yet.

Another solution might be to try using settings/general/keyboard/add new shortcut to make shortcuts you find convenient for the extra characters.